# How to resolve iPhone 7 running iOS 13.1.2 not supported by Xcode 10.1?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, xcode

When trying to run my test app on my iPhone 7, I got this message:

> could not locate device support files.

This iPhone 7 (model 1660,1778, 1779, 1780) is running iOS 13.1.2 (17A860), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

My Xcode is version 10.1. I tried to update Xcode to latest from App Store. It never works - the coloured ball keeps spinning. What I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Xcode 11 installed for this to work. Xcode 10.x won't recognize iOS 13.

Try logging out and in of App Store app on your Mac. If it doesn't work you try restarting your Mac. If that fails too, attempt a reinstall of Xcode from the App Store.

Comment: My mac is running High Sierra 10.13.6. Could that be the reason that I cannot upgrade to xcode 11?

Comment: @Zhifang Yes. Xcode 11 requires at least macOS 10.14.4 to be installed. What's the model of your Mac? Possibly your Mac doesn't support running macOS Mojave.

Comment: It is MacBook Pro 2018.

Comment: @Zhifang Your MacBook is pretty good to go. I use a 2013 MacBook Pro which is still going strong and will run macOS Catalina 10.15.